# AJAX in codeigniter redirects to server homepage

Tags: jquery, url, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter and curently implementing ajax operations. My view page is :

```
    <p>
    <?php echo 'Customer Name :' ;?>

    <?php
    echo form_dropdown('loan_customer_id', $loan_cust,'','class="loancustlist" id="loancust"'); ?>
    </p>
<div id="cinfo">
    OP here
</div>
```

The javascript codes are :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#loancust').change(function(){
        var lcid = $('#loancust').val();
        $.ajax({ url : "/index.php/ajax/show_customer_loan_info",
                 success : function(result)
                 {
                     $('#cinfo').html(result);
                 }});
        });
   });
```

And the controller `ajax` is :

```
 function show_customer_loan_info()
    {
        echo 'Success !';
    }
```

But instead of displaying `Success !` in div `cinfo`, the page redirects to the server home page( in my case its `wampserver`), with the html form at the top of the webpage. Where I have done the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $.ajax({ url : "/index.php/ajax/show_customer_loan_info",
```

to:

```
 $.ajax({ url : "http://sitename/index.php/ajax/show_customer_loan_info",
```

i implemented your code and used the network control with the google chrome browser to see the  it was not seeing the ajax controller.  seemed to work fine after that full URL was entered

if however your are embedding the form in a larger page, you may way to put a return false in the javascript change event.  this will force the javascript to stop propagation and submit a form.

good luck with your project!